# How to make a hyperlink for a point layer in QGIS so that you can go to Google Maps

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, hyperlink

How to make a hyperlink for a point layer in QGIS so that you can go to Google Maps.

I need to have a separate field when clicked it will show me that point on Google Maps.

Comment: What do you with "box"?

Comment: Are your point coordinates in lat long?

Answer (score 7):

Google Maps URL is like: https://www.google.de/maps/@52.3967404,1.4891383,12.04z

The first 2 numbers after maps/@ are you coordinates (lat, long). Be careful you have the correct order! The last number is just Zoom! Then you can do the following:

1. Transform you coordinates if needed (You can do it with Field calculator)
2. Generate the URLs (You can do this also with Field calculator)

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer to my question

`'<a href="'||'https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/' || to_string( y(transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:5563', 'EPSG:4326'))) || ',' || to_string( x( transform( $geometry, 'EPSG:5563', 'EPSG:4326'))) || '">Open Google Map</a>'`